# return an array from an int method in c++

Tags: c++

i am writing a code for a multidimensional array with two functions.
First function(`read()`) gets the value of each array, and the second one shows each of them.

My problem is return the gotten array from the read function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>
#include<cassert>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;
typedef int Sec[2][2];
int read(Sec sec){
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            cin>>sec[i][j];
        }
    }
    return  sec;
}
void sho(){
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            cout<<sec[i][j];
        }
    }   
}

int main() {

    read(Sec sec);
    sho(sec);   
}
```

Comment: Please notice that formatting your code correctly matters a lot. Also `read(Sec sec);` is wrong. You probably wanted `Sec sec; read(sec);`.

Comment: Your code does not even compile, could you at least provide a functional example? (See [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you done? Typedef ing int for Sec[][]? Why? Don't typedef int or any other reserved keywords

Comment: return type: std::array<>?

Comment: @M.shahbazi check the answers below

Comment: Your description of your problem is a bit sparse: _"return the gotten array from the read function"_. How is this a problem? Is this return happening and you don't want it to? Is this not happening and you want it to? Is it partially happening but not completely? Concrete symptoms are usually better than vague descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your mistakes:

1. You don't need to return anything from `read` function because argument passed to this function is passed as pointer. Therefore, content on these addresses will be updated based on user input. This is perfectly fine function signature `void read(Sec sec);`
2. In your `main` function, you need first to initialize your local variable `Sec sec;` and then pass it to `read` function like this `read(sec);`

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
//you dont need ctime here
#include <ctime>
//you dont need csdtlib here
#include <cstdlib>
//you dont need cmath here
#include <cmath>
//you dont need time.h here
#include <time.h>
//you dont need cassert here
#include<cassert>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
system("pause") or input loop */

using namespace std;
typedef int Sec[2][2];

//by adding the "&" symbol you give the function read a refrenze to a variable of 
//type sec, which allows to change the values, it is like a derefrenzed pointer  
void read(Sec& sec){
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            cin>>sec[i][j];
        }
    }
}

//you dont need a refrenze here, because u just want to read from the Sec object, if 
//you want to run a bit faster you couldnt use:
//void show(const Sec& sec),
//this would give the function show a refrenze you cant edit, so perfectly for 
//reading values
void show(Sec sec){
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            cout<<sec[i][j];
        }
    } 
}

int main() {
    Sec sec;
    read(sec);
    show(sec)
}
```